# Browse a website automatically after opening a browser

Tags: mobile-website

Suppose you install a browser APK file, after opening the browser, my website automatically loaded. Is it possible?

Suppose i provide a custom name browser apk to my client. Then my client install it to his android device. when he open the browser my website automatically loaded. How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "browser'? Do you just mean an app built from your website?